# SSRS Reporting in Blazor

Tags: reporting-services, blazor

Has anyone had any success with integrating SSRS reporting with Blazor?  If so how and what did you use?

I would like to utilize my existing rdl files in Blazor(Client and Server).

I've tried BoldReports but didn't have much success in getting it to work and I'm currently investigating Radzen but there is very little documentation to go by.

Comment: Have you considered Telerik Reporting? It's fully compatible with Blazor for both reporting and editing reports https://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx

Comment: Telerik told me I would have to create my reports ground up in order to use their controls.  I want to leverage my existing reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can try report viewer from [Bold Reports](https://www.boldreports.com/embedded-reporting/blazor-report-viewer)

You can use it to view reports from external servers, Microsoft SSRS, SharePoint, your local system, or those embedded in any applications.

I personally tried the updated version of bold reports. It's not very straight forward though, but the best option available in current scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Radzen control doesn't work. I would agree there's not much documentation, and the support forum just says to go and read the scant info there is. I'm thinking Bold Reports too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).